# Eloquent Query Scope on Relationships

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have two models, App\Song (belongsTo App\Host) and App\Host (hasMany App\Song).

I have the following query in my Controller:

```
$songs = Song::whereHas('host', function($query) {
                $query->where('skip_threshold', '>', \DB::raw('songs.attempts'))
                      ->where('active', 1);
            })
->whereNull('downloaded')
->get();
```

For reusability I would like to turn into a query scope(s).

I'm quite new to Eloquent so I'm not sure this is the correct way to do this being that its two Models as its not returning any results (where there should be).

**Song.php**

```
public function scopeEligable($query)
{
    $query->where('skip_threshold', '>', \DB::raw('songs.attempts'));
}

public function scopeActiveHost($query)
{
    $query->where('active', 1);
}

public function scopeInDownloadQueue($query)
{
    $query->whereNull('downloaded');
}
```

Comment: What's the code in your controller that you're using to call those query scopes? (that aren't returning results?)

Comment: `Song::eligable()->activehost()->indownloadqueue()->get();`

Comment: you should have `return` in all your scopes..  `return $query->whereNull('downloaded');`.  Scopes should always return a query builder instance.  https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent#query-scopes

Comment: I have updated the scopes to return query but no data is still returned

Comment: you probably need to take a look at the sql directly. do you have DebugBar installed?  if not try this before your query call...

\Event::listen('illuminate.query', function($query, $params, $time, $conn)
        {
            dd(array($query, $params, $time, $conn));
        });

Comment: If I remove eligable() and activehost() scopes from my call results are returned, both of those scopes belong to the Host model, should they be moved in there?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You should put scopes into Models they belong to. Looking at your initial query scopes `scopeEligable` and `scopeActiveHost` belongs to `Host` model, so you should move them into `Host` model and then you'll be able to use your query using scopes like this:

```
$songs = Song::whereHas('host', function($query) {
   $query->eligable()->activeHost();
})->inDownloadedQueue()->get();
```

and as already pointed in comment you should add `return` to each scope so they could be used as they intended.

**EDIT**

If you would like to make using it shorter, you could create new relationship in `Song` model:

```
public function activeHost() 
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Host:class)->eligable()->activeHost();
}
```

so now, you could write:

```
$songs = Song::whereHas('activeHost')->inDownloadedQueue()->get();
```

Comment: This works as expected, however this still requires three lines of code, in the code for simplicity is there a way a this can be shortened to a single line?

Comment: Hi Marcin, I am using the code now and it doesn't seem to be working as expected. I have tried using `->toSql()` function to debug and get the following SQL generated: `select * from "songs" where exists (select * from "hosts" where "songs"."host_id" = "hosts"."id" and "skip_threshold" > songs.attempts and "active" = ?) and "downloaded" is null`. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I think you're mistaken about 2 models. I think this should work

**Song.php**

```
public function scopeEligable($query, $active) {
   return $query->whereHas('host', function($q) {
       $q->where('skip_threshold', '>', \DB::raw('songs.attempts'))->where('active', $active);
   })
}

public function scopeInDownloadQueue($query)
{
   $query->whereNull('downloaded');
}
```

**Usage**

```
$songs = Song::eligable(true)->inDownloadQueue()->get();
```